# Accessing super class's hidden fields while using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, hiddenfield

I will explain it through an example since I am not able to explain the problem.

Let's take 2 classes as below,

```
public class Vehicle {
    public String series = "Sedan";
}

public class Audi extends Vehicle {
    public String series = "A8";
}
```

Now, I want to get both the series of Vehicle and Audi. So I can use,

```
Audi audi = new Audi();
Vehicle vehicle = audi;
String audiSeries = audi.series; //This will give me "A8"
String vehicleSeries = vehicle.series; //This will give me "Sedan"
```

**Here comes my problem:**
But If I don't have access to `Vehicle` and `Audi` classes during compilation and can only use reflection to get the object, how can I get the `vehicle's series`.

```
Class audiClass = Class.forName("Audi");
Class vehicleClass = Class.forName("Vehicle");

Object audiObj = audiClass.newInstance();
Field audiSeries = audiClass.getField("series");

System.out.println(audiSeries.get(audiObj));
```

> Output: **A8**
>
> Is there anyway to get `Vehicle` class' `series` field **"Sedan"** in
>   the above method.

**P.S:** I cannot change the design to avoid this problem.

Comment: Try `audiClass.getDeclaredField("series")`. This finds all fields if the class in question (but not of parent classes).

Comment: @UweAllner, as you have mentioned even that only returns the object's class's field.. Not parents. But in this case, I want the parent's field.

Comment: Then you will have to extract the parent class with `getSuperclass()` and call it on this one.

Comment: Set the accessibility of the field to true by using `field.setAccessible(true)`. then you can

Comment: @UweAllner, your suggestion works... Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was suprised myself, that you can access the Vehicle's Field by just casting ist to a Vehicle.

Your Approch works, you just have to go the last step by using the Field from the Vehicle-Class:

```
Audi audi = new Audi();
Vehicle vehicle = audi;
String audiSeries = audi.series; 
System.out.println("direct-audi: " + audiSeries);
String vehicleSeries = vehicle.series; 
System.out.println("direct-vehicle: " + vehicleSeries);


Class audiClass = Class.forName(Audi.class.getName());
Class vehicleClass = Class.forName(Vehicle.class.getName());


Object audiObj = audiClass.newInstance();
Field audiSeriesField = audiClass.getField("series");
Field vehicleSeriesField = vehicleClass.getField("series");

System.out.println("reflection-audi: " + audiSeriesField.get(audiObj));
System.out.println("reflection-vehicle: " +  vehicleSeriesField.get(audiObj));
```

Result:

```
direct-audi: A8
direct-vehicle: Sedan
reflection-audi: A8
reflection-vehicle: Sedan
```

If you dont Know the Superclass Name you can just use `Class vehicleClass  = audiClass.getSuperclass();`

Comment: I figured this out thanks to @UweAller's suggestion.. But when I came here I saw the answer... Thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a `getter` in the super class this will do the trick for you:

```
public class Audi extends Vehicle {
    String myString = "A8";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(new Audi().myString);        // outputs A8
        System.out.println(new Audi().getMyString());   // outputs Sedan
    }

}

class Vehicle {
    String myString = "Sedan";

    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **could** solve it this way:

```
Field someField = someClass.getDeclaredField("fieldname");
someField.setAccessible(true);
Object val = someField.get(someObj);
```

But this is **not** what reflection is supposed to be used for and in general a rather ugly solution you shouldn't use. Apart from that these operations are rather costly. You should simply implement a getter-method for the required fields instead. If you need to use the above solution you should consider redesigning the complete thing, since this is far away from clean OOP.